# How to export array to Excel worksheet?

Tags: vb.net

I have an array with 4 columns and close to 25 rows. I want to know how to export it to an excel sheet. I'd like the elements in the array to appear at once inn the excel sheet when run.

Dim matrix(4,25) As String

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In VB.Net, how to write an Array to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691009/in-vb-net-how-to-write-an-array-to-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do it in vb.net, this should do it.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim oExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook As Object = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")
    Dim oSheet As Object = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim matrix(4, 25) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    'populate matrix
    For i = 1 To 4
        For j = 1 To 25
            matrix(i, j) = i & "  " & j
        Next j
    Next i

    'move to excel worksheet
    For i = 1 To 4
        For j = 1 To 25
            oSheet.cells(j, i).Value = matrix(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    'Save this Excel document
    oBook.SaveAs("C:\Book1.xls", True)
    oExcel.Quit()
End Sub
```